# Deploy without dbDacFx with Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website. I have published many PHP websites before but this is my first attempt to deploy an Asp.Net MVC website. Here are the steps I took to deploy the website:

1. I went to my host's panel, created a website and changed its settings.
2. I created a database user and a database and added the user to that database.
3. I then went to a tab named "Web Publishing" and clicked on *Download Publishing Profile for this web site*.
4. Went to Visual Studio, right clicked on the project name, clicked the "Publish" option and then imported the downloaded file. Hit next but the connection strings for databases were not there.
5. I opened the file with Notepad++ and copied the connection string to my database context. Clicked both checkboxes "Use this connec..." and "Execute code first migr....". And on the other connection both the "Update database" and "Use..."
6. I ran the publish but it fails with this message:

`Unable to perform the operation. Please contact your server administrator to check authorization and delegation settings.`

What do you think the problem is?

Also, is there a way that I can manually deploy this website with all the configurations that Visual Studio does (for instance bundling CSS and JS files, updating web.config, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two types of databases in your project.  One uses EF Code First, and the other is a regular SQL database.  It's the latter one that is using dbDacFx, which is a feature shipped with Web Deploy.  Your hoster has to provide some configuration settings for dbDacFx to work correctly, and it seems that they haven't.

(As a workaround, if you can connect to the DB directly from your own machine, you can deploy to your machine and keep the dbDacFx settings, and it will effect the changes on the database server.)

Side note: The EF Code First stuff only happens at runtime and hence doesn't really impact the publish process in any way.

As for your second question: the publish feature in VS does all the work through MSBuild.  Once your profile is configured, you can do the same thing through the command line, e.g.

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=MyProfileName
```

Comment: I wish you posted this answer sooner. I spent almost a whole day playing with the settings, changing each option and in the end I just did this!! I first uploaded the content through FTP and then changed the connectionstring of my project to the remote db and ran the initializer. It worked perfectly.